# Rendering clean & tidy HTML with TWIG templates

Tags: php, templates, twig

I've been playing with [`Twig`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) (version `1.9.1`) as a `PHP` templating engine, and I'm not totally satisfied with the rendered `HTML` as extra unwanted line-breaks and spaces are added which make the result quite untidy. To make my templates more flexible, I am using [`macros`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) which can call each other in a nested fashion, which in itself works fine, but seems to make things worse. For instance, a `<a>` element is rendered as follows:

```
             <a href="http://google.com" alt="some alternative text">                    some text with <strong>some html</strong>



</a>
```

I know that part of the reason is the way my `twig` templates are formatted, as if I remove empty lines and indenting from them, the rendered `HTML` looks a bit more tidy, but not completely: **the below output shows a rendered `<a>` with still 2 line breaks between the start and end of the element, despite the corresponding template not containing any empty lines or spaces!**:

```
<a href="http://google.com" alt="some alternative text">some text with <strong>some html</strong>


</a>
```

Even though it helps, removing formatting from my `twig` templates (i.e. empty lines and indenting) isn't really an option as it makes my template very hard to read and maintain.

**Apart from removing formatting from templates. what are the ways to render a cleaner/tidier HTML with `Twig`?**

Comment: If you want absolute control over the whitespace in your output, just use PHP. TBH I have never understood why templating engines for PHP like Twig and Smarty even *exist*, PHP was designed to be a HTML templating engine in and of itself, and while it is a little verbose when used in this fashion it give's you more control over what happens to the end result than any of these abstraction layers ever do. [*With just one more layer of abstraction, I can take over the world!*](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx)

Comment: From a front-end POV I see the benefit of a templating engine: syntax more human-readable/intuitive + similarities across engines, even from different languages (Django:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/, Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) which must help with working on different projects. From a back-end POV, I see the benefit from the engine's internal routines (e.g. escaping) which facilitate a consistent and safe rendering of content. However in my case I think I will be better off with pure `PHP` as I can do something simpler and faster by myself.

Comment: @DaveRandom You've clearly never worked on SAAS style projects then - a very narrow-minded point of view you've got. Take for example a hosted website system, lets just say its a hosted blog for this example. What happens if the hosted user wants to edit the design? You'd be an idiot to allow them to use PHP, so Twig is an ideal candidate, especially with its sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page of the documentation should help you control spaces within tags http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control

Comment: I don't think that's wat he meant or needs, you can remove all whitespace or remove it in front or at the end.. But he just wants clean structured html, and that's not (yet) possible with the whitespace-control of twig.

Comment: The OP never replied to say either way but did accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted correct output indentation too, so I made an extension for that. I made it available in a gist: https://gist.github.com/urraka/ccd1812570ca4b278b9f

See the usage file from the gist for a bit of an explanation.

Basically, this template:

```
{# Given variable = "line1\nline2\nline3" #}

<body>
    {% if true %}
        <stuff>{% if true %}only blocks that take the whole line have effect{% endif %}</stuff>
        {{ variable }}
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

would end up like this:

```
<body>
    <stuff>only blocks that take the whole line have effect</stuff>
    line1
    line2
    line3
</body>
```

Comment: In other words, not possible with vanilla Twig, even in 2017? Anyway, good job on the extension! Looks to me as if this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although this bundle is no longer maintained, it might be a start to write a tidy service with tidy_parse_string(). [KnpMarkupValidatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkupValidatorBundle)